# How to Effectively use Concurrency of Cloud Run

Tags: python

We are trying to hit a cloud run service using a for loop in python.
What we expect from our for loop is that it bombards the service with request hits so that the service scales and add more container instances to cater to the requests.
But on the contrary what we are witnessing is that our for loop waits for the service to complete the response and then makes another hit which usually takes around 30 seconds to complete. So effectively we are able to make only 2 hits per minute.
What can we do to make sure that the hits are made right one after the other and does not wait for the service to complete the task for each hit.

```py
for i in range(len(checkin_list)):

    todo = { 
          "hotelurl_json"  :  hotel_dict ,
            "checkin"      :  checkin_list[i] ,
            "checkout"     :  checkout_list[i]
        }
         
    
    requests.post(api_url, json=todo)
```

I have attached screenshot the system configuration and of the metrics screen
[Cloud Run service configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtKA3.png)

[Metrics screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUuc1.png)

Comment: Your problem is not with Cloud Run or the cloud. To issue multiple requests at the same time, use **concurrency**. Delete the Stack Overflow tags that are not part of your problem. The only tag should be Python.

Comment: After your edit. Your problem has nothing to do with Cloud Run or Google Cloud. I removed the spamming tags.

Comment: Ok @JohnHanley i will keep in mind